# psycopg2 has results from invalid connection

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I was using psycopg2 to connect to my local instance of postgres but didn't realize I never set the env vars.  I decided to do a select on a sys table (information_schema.tables) to check if I had connected and it came back with results.  I was confused for a long time trying to figure out why i wasn't getting the desired results back.

What is going on under the hood to cause this and why didn't psycopg2 just error out and say it was an invalid connection?

```
import psycopg2


conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host=None,
                port=None,
                dbname=None,
                user=None,
                password=None,
            )

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables
limit 3 """)

print(cur.fetchall())
```

results:

> [('pg_statistic',), ('pg_foreign_table',), ('pg_authid',)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, the connection is valid. When you pass null arguments to `psycopg2.connect()` like you have done then the program gets [Postgres environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) which are apparently set up properly. Note that this is not true in the case you pass a DSN string to the function:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=None") # this defines an invalid connection
```

Per [the documentation](http://psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect):

> The PostgreSQL documentation contains the complete list of the [supported parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS). Also note that the same parameters can be passed to the client library using [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html).